# What can we say about $\sum_i K_i K_i^\dagger$ for non-unital CPTP maps?

Tags: quantum-operation, kraus-representation

Suppose we have a CPTP map $\Phi(\rho)=\sum_i K_i \rho K_i^+$, such that, $\sum_i K_i^+K_i=\mathbb{I}$.

In case the map preserves Identity, is *unital*, then we immediately have $\sum_i K_i K_i^+ =\mathbb{I}$.
What can we say about the sum $\sum_i K_i K_i^+$ when the map is not unital?
Can we write relations/inequalities like $\sum_i K_i K_i^+ \leq \mathbb{I}$?

Comment: Note that saying $\Phi(X)=\sum_i K_i X K_i^*$ is CPTP is equivalent to the condition that $\sum_i K_i^*K_i=I$ so its not necessary to include it as an extra assumption.

Comment: Of course, thought it best to write it explicitly.

Comment: Please don't change the question (in the sense of asking a different question) after answers have been given. This invalidates existing answers. Ask a new question, referring to this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $d$ be the dimension of the system. Since $\sum_i K_iK_i^\dagger = \Phi(\mathbb 1) = d \Phi(\mathbb 1/d)$, it can be $d$ times any quantum state (by, e.g., setting $\Phi$ as a replacement channel). In other words, it can be any trace-$d$ positive semi-definite operator.

Concretely, for a single qubit, by setting $K_0 = |{0}\rangle\langle{0}|$, $K_1 = |{0}\rangle\langle{1}|$, we have $\sum_i K_iK_i^\dagger = 2|{0}\rangle\langle{0}|\nleq\mathbb 1$.

Comment: As I understand it, unless we have more information about a specific map, we are not able to say anything better than this?

Comment: Yes, as this shows $\sum_i K_i K_i^\dagger$ must be a trace-$d$ positive semi-definite operator (since $\Phi$ is CPTP) and can be any such operator. We are not able to say anything better without more restriction of $\Phi$.

Answer (score 2):

One can show concretely that a $\tfrac1d\Phi(I)$ can be *any* density matrix $\sigma$. To this end, simply choose
$$
\Phi(\rho)  = \mathrm{tr}(\rho)\,\sigma\ .
$$
It can be straightforwardly checked it is CP, e.g., by computing the Choi state, or just by realizing it describes a simple physical process: Throw away the input and prepare a state $\sigma$ as the output.

Comment: But if there are two parties and one was modelling LOCC, such a map would not arise, would it?

Comment: @Cain You could prepare any separable state with LOCC.